# Calling std::to_string or std::to_wstring based on given typedef

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, enable-if

In a library I am internally using typedefs of the following form:

```cpp
using AnsiChar = char;
using WideChar = wchar_t;
```

A global typedef that basically stores the platform-specific `char` to be used in the entire library is defined like this:

```cpp
// Either
using Char = AnsiChar;
// or
using Char = WideChar;
// depending on the platform this code is being compiled on
```

At some point in the code I want to either call `std::to_string` or `std::to_wstring` depending on the current `Char` type. My attempt looks like this:

```cpp
template <typename TChar = Char, typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<TChar, AnsiChar>::value, std::string>::type
ToString(const T& Arg)
{
    return std::to_string(Arg);
}

template <typename TChar = Char, typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<TChar, WideChar>::value, std::wstring>::type
ToString(const T& Arg)
{
    return std::to_wstring(Arg);
}
```

Is this the correct way to implement a conditional function or is there any other way that is recommended to accomplish this?

---

*EDIT.* As a side-note I was considering to work with function pointers using something like `std::basic_string<Char>` as the return type to generalize this and then somehow conditionally bind either of `std::to_string` or `std::to_wstring` to the pointer.

Comment: Given that the caller needs to know the type of the returned string, how do you propose to use this generically? Are you going to define a generic string type `using string_type = std::basic_string<Char>;`? But that also will knock on into the rest of your code. For example how will you `std::cout` the returned *string* from one of these functions?

Comment: @Galik As you have noticed, I have a wrapper class that has a `std::basic_string<Char>` member and basically I am supplying the class with `ToString(...).c_str()` since it expects a `const Char*` in its constructor which fits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<class Char>
struct string_traits;
template<>
struct string_traits<char>{
  using string=std::string;
  template<class T>
  static string convert_to_string(T&& t){
    using std::to_string;
    return to_string(std::forward<T>(t));
  }
};
template<>
struct string_traits<wchar_t>{
  using string=std::wstring;
  template<class T>
  static string convert_to_string(T&& t){
    using std::to_wstring;
    return to_wstring(std::forward<T>(t));
  }
};
```

now your code is simply

```
template <typename TChar = Char, typename T>
std::basic_string<TChar>
ToString(const T& Arg) {
  return string_traits<TChar>::convert_to_string(Arg);
}
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are writing `using string = std::string` / `using string = std::wstring` and `using std::to_string` / `using std::to_wstring` instead of inlining those directly since they are only used once?

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic The former two is for writing `string_traits<T>::string`. The latter two is for ADL.

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic Consumers of `string_traits<T>` can do `string_traits<T>::string` and get their string type.  The using directive lets you , for a type `foo::bar`, write a `std::string foo::to_string(bar const&)` and `string_traits<T>::convert_to_string` will pick it up automatically (ADL).

Comment: Pardon me, although I can follow your explanation for `string_traits<T>::string` (which is basically a typesafe alias for `std::basic_string<T>`) I am struggling to understand the using directive inside `convert_to_string`. Do you have another example, or a link where I can read up on that particularly?

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl -- `namespace foo{ struct bar {}; std::string to_string( bar const& ) { return "bar"; } }`.  Given that, `string_traits<char>::convert_to_string( bar{} )` returns `"bar"s`.  A direct call to `std::to_string` would not find that `foo::to_string` function meanwhile.